# Problema al insertar texto en una etiqueta span [object Text]

Tags: javascript

En qué estoy fallando ya que no me inserta el texto y solo me aparece '[object Text]' ya intenté cambiando innerHTML por appendChild pero sigue sin funcionar

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = document.createTextNode("added text");
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">ADD TEXT</button>

<span id="text"></span>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### La diferencia entre `.appendChild(node);` y `.innerHTML = htmlCode;`

### appendChild

> `appendChild` inserta un nodo al final del elemento especificado en el
>   `DOM`. Requiere un parametro `node`  ► `.appendChild(node);`

Ejemplo de uso:

```
.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hola SOES"));
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = document.createTextNode("added text");
  document.getElementById("text").appendChild(text);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">ADD TEXT</button>

<span id="text"></span>
```

### innerHTML

> `innerHTML` es una propiedad del `DOM` que permite **remplazar** el `html`
>   de un elemento que se parsea (convierte) directamente en nodos del
>   `DOM`.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
.innerHTML = "<div>Hola SOES</div>";
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = "added text";
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">ADD TEXT</button>

<span id="text"></span>
```

---

**Respuesta:**

Después de tener esto claro, tu has intentado una fusión de ambas, has comentado que tampoco te funciona cambiando `innerHTML` por `appendChild`, a lo que supongo que tu error ha sido hacer `.appendChild = text;` en vez de `.appendChild(text);`.  Recomendación al uso de `textContent` antes que `innerHTML` o `innerText`, explicación abajo del todo.

---

### Información adicional:

**innerText VS innerHTML**

`innerText` es mejor respecto a seguridad, no edita el html como tal.

**Source:
[innerText vs innerHTML](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/innertext-vs-innerhtml)**

`innerHTML` es mejor en rendimiento (pese a que `innerHTML` tiene que parsear el HTML), el `innerText` se preocupa del estilo del texto por lo que puede llegar a tardar mas.

**Source: [Performance innerText vs innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256864/why-does-replacing-innerhtml-with-innertext-causes-15x-drop-in-performance)**

`textContent` es mejor **SIEMPRE**, en rendimiento por no se preocupa del estilo ni tiene que parsear HTML, y en seguridad por que tampoco edita el HTML.

Comment: ¿Para añadir texto a un span no es mejor usar `.innerText`?

Comment: @FernandoCarrascosa, Gracias a tu pregunta he investigado y descubierto que es mejor respecto a seguridad, no edita el html como tal. [innerText vs innerHTML](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/innertext-vs-innerhtml) Pero en rendimiento no (pese a que `innerHTML` tiene que parsear el HTML), el `innerText` se preocupa del estilo del texto por lo que puede llegar a tardar mas. [Performance innerText vs innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256864/why-does-replacing-innerhtml-with-innertext-causes-15x-drop-in-performance). En resumen lo mejor es usar `textContent` para textos planos.

Comment: Claro, .innerText te escapa las etiquetas HTML que haya en el contenido y devuelve sólo texto. Supongo que el uso depende del contexto.

Answer (score 2):

Borre esta linea `document.createTextNode`, abajo dejo el ejemplo

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text = "added text";
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">ADD TEXT</button>

<span id="text"></span>
```